# Quartz expression every hour

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I wanted to clarify which of the below expressions are meant to execute the cron job every hour all the time? I have EXPRESSION_1 configured to run every hour but am noticing some weird behavior with the cron skipping the job for a few hours. Can someone clarify please

```
    EXPRESSION_1=0 0 * * * ?
    EXPRESSION_2=0 0/0 * * * ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first expression looks correct and will execute every hour.

As your requirement is once per hour you could also use a quartz `SimpleTrigger` and avoid using a cron expression.